# Ceiling Fan with light kit and remote on 2 different switches

Tags: electrical

I want to install a ceiling fan that has a led light kit and an included remote control 2 different wall switches (one for fan and one for light).

The fan only has 3 wires (one for the motor, one for neutral, and one ground). There is no wire for the light. There are 4 wires coming out of the ceiling to use 2 switches and I would like to use the existing wiring in my house.

My question is how can I wire the fan to control the light and the fan on 2 seperate switches that are in my house. The fan also has an included remote control that I would like to use, if possible.

Instructions for the fan:
https://images.atgstores.com/pdf/278/irenehuggerlk-installation.pdf

Answer (score 2):

You can't... Well, you can't use separate switches to control the fan and light, and also use the remote. So you'll have to decide if you want to use two wall switches, or the remote.

The reason that there's only three wires coming out of the fan unit, is because you're only supplying power to the remote module. The remote module then controls the fan and light, depending on what buttons are pressed on the remote control. If you pull out the remote module, you'll find four wires going from it to the fan unit. One wire for neutral, one for ground, one for the lights, and one for the fan.

#### If you just want to use the remote control.

1. Connect the ground from the ceiling, to the ground from the remote module in the fan.
2. Connect the neutral from the ceiling, to the neutral from the remote module in the fan.
3. Connect the "hot" wire from one of the switches, to the "hot" wire from the remote module in the fan.
4. Cap off the extra "hot" wire from the other wall switch.

#### If you want to use two wall switches

1. Remove the remote module from the fan.
2. Connect the ground wire from the ceiling, to the ground wire(s) in the fan unit.
3. Connect the neutral from the ceiling, to the neutral(s) in the fan unit.
4. Connect the "hot" wire from one of the wall switches, to one of the "hot" wires from the fan unit.
5. Connect the "hot" wire from the other wall switch, to the other "hot" wire from the fan unit.

If you want to use the remote for the light or fan, and a wall switch for the other. That can also be accomplished, but I'm not going to cover it here.

Comment: Yeah, the remote module on his fan looks to be integrated with the fan in a most undesirable way, as well...(there's no information in the manual about how the remote is wired to the fan)

Comment: So if I decide on the 2 separate switch method,how will I be able to change the speed of the fan? Is there a solution for this? Thank you.

Comment: @user63499 you'll either have to use a wall mounted speed control, or the pull switch on the fan (if it has one).